# How to save a checkbox checked state as a boolean?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, boolean, converters

How to save a checkbox checked state as a boolean?

**ASP.NET**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" runat="Server" />
```

**VB**

```
Dim cb As Boolean = cb.Checked
```

---

The above code produces the following error:

*'checked' is not a member of 'boolean'*

Comment: What means the _NOT_ in: _"How can the checked state of a checkbox NOT in a gridview be converted to a boolean result?"_ ? If it's not in a `GridView` where is it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter its just stand alone on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can the checked state of a checkbox   be converted
>   to a boolean result?

The `Checked` property already returns a `Boolean`, so your question is somewhat confusing.

However, the name of your CheckBox is `cb`, you have used the same name for your `Boolean` variable. Then you want `cb.Checked` which is the `Boolean` not the `CheckBox`.

If it's already on top of the page you can reference it directly:

```
Dim isCheckBoxChecked As Boolean = cb.Checked  ' no need to search the reference '
```

You should choose meaningful names for your variables and controls.

Comment: @Obsidion: still confusing. If it's not in a gridview you don't need to find it. You can use it directly since ASP.NET will declare it automatically in the partial `designer.VB`-file. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I simply want to get the checkbox checked state and save it as a boolean. The code above produces the error noted.

Comment: @Obsidion: ... and i've explained the reason. You use the same name for the boolean which you use for the control.

Comment: Thanks Tim, simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

since your question is bit unclear

what about the following ??

```
Private Function cbChecked(ByVal ctrlCb As CheckBox) As Boolean
    If ctrlCb.Checked Then
        cbChecked = True
    Else
        cbChecked = False
    End If
    Return cbChecked
End Function



Dim blncb As Boolean = cbChecked(cb)
```

Comment: Everyone was saying it is unclear. I dont see how it can be clearer. That's the code I have and that's the error it produces. The answer was simple the variable cant be the same as the id. +1 for this anyway, thanks.